# Send information from one android client to many android clients

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

Could you tell me, please, how could I send Information from one android client to many android clients in these two possibilities shown below?

> 1) the request from the client goes to the server and from the server to the other clients. Here I know that from the client to the server I can use webservice. My doubt is how to send information from the server the clients when the server has certain information. In this case the clients don't know when they needs to fetch information from the server. Just the server knows when it has to send information to the clients.
>
> 2) the request goes direct from the client to the other clients.

Comment: The first approach should work, search for android push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send information to other devices.

Firstly you need to [register](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk) each client device in your backend.
In this way, assuming that you want to send information to a group of devices from a device. your backend could know the devices to send the information.

Then your backend will need to [send](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol) the information and the token devices to the FCM server, this server will send the information for each devices that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the android push notification.
Once the server retrieves the certain information from the android client(request from client to webservice via httprequest) you can send the push notification from the server to the multiple android clients and once client receives the push notification you can do your certain task.

Answer (score 0):

For Android to server your webservice approach should work fine. For server to Android you can use Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). FCM requires setting up an app server that sends the data to Google which then sends the data to Android clients that have subscribed to that content. A quick way to have the whole thing up and running would be to use AeroGear https://aerogear.org/docs/unifiedpush/aerogear-push-android/. You can even get it hosted for free at OpenShift https://www.openshift.com/.

The steps would be as follows:

1. Create an Aerogear container (self-hosted or cloud hosted e.g. @ openshift)
2. Register with Google FCM for push notifications and get the SenderID and Secret (which you would need to add to Aerogear)
3. Create a servlet that listens for the changes from the clients (can also be hosted at openshift) and sends the notifications to Aerogear (using Aerogear's Java API) which would in turn send them to Google FCM